# Fill ImageView to screen whilst maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two image files:

- 320dpi 768x1280
- 480dpi 1080x1920

I have placed each image in the xhdpi and xxhdpi drawables folder of my project respectively. I am trying to get both images to scale appropriately and fill the screen without any whitespace.

My XML code is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.vax.gamurs.LandingPage"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/LandingBack"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I am getting whitespace on the sides of both the Nexus 4 and the Nexus 5. How can I eliminate the whitespace and have the image fill the screen whilst maintaining aspect ratio?

[image: Nexus4]

Comment: Since the aspect ratio of the image is different from the aspect ratio of the screen, you can't. Your choice is between having whitespace on the borders or cropping the image.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek What aspect ratio should I be using to ensure that the screen is filled?

Comment: Depends on the device. There is not one universal aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `scaleType="centerCrop"` as follows:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/LandingBack"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

The above method will crop the image. Unfortunately this is a drawback if you use fixed size drawables and want to support different screen sizes.

Alternate way would be to use a 9-patch image as attached below. This will stretch the blue background to fill the empty space.

Download link for 9Patch image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2411239/sampleimg.9.png

Here is a sample screenshot, showing how it will work:

[image]

**Update:**

Your new `ImageView` should be as follows:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/LandingBack"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/sampleimg"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Also for reference, I use 1px stretch patch as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: centreCrop makes me lose part of the image due to cropping.

Comment: @OsborneCox unfortunately this is the drawback if you have a fixed size image (especially with all devices with different sizes). You could use a nine patch drawable instead, which would auto scale the blue background to fill the white area. let me know if you need more info about this method.

Comment: How can I use a nine patch drawable appropriately in this instance? Scaling the blue background would be perfect as it would retain the size/ratio of the text and buttons.

Comment: Thanks very much for the example. I was wondering how you specified the points to use so that the text wouldn't get stretched. I tried to re-create what you did in the 9 patch tool and it doesn't look right.

Comment: Also, if I am using a nine patch image, are the XML ImageView settings you've specified remain except for the centreCrop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62022/discussion-between-osborne-cox-and-amulya-khare).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fill while keeping the aspect ratio, as that doesnt make sense. What you can do is set the background to same as the blue color. (very simple to do) or either have the image fill only the height or only the width using simple maths

w = W;
h = (w/W) H;

where W is width of screen, H is height of screen, w is width of image and h is height of image

Interchange width with height to fill the whole height rather than width

Answer (score 0):

Try to set background of imageview like this:

```
    android:background="@drawable/background"
```

instead of "src". If you use src, your image will not scale but background will be scaled.

But this scaling can destroy your image, you should use nine-patch.

Answer (score -1):

Just use property of Imageview

```
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

that means

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/LandingBack"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

in Imageview and you are done.Happy Coding

Comment: This causes the image to be stretched.